# Statistical operation between two data frame in R

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe

I have two large data frame, one with simulation data and the other one with observation data.
The columns represent the points where I want to compare and the rows the hours.

```
dim(SIM)
[1]  400 1000 

dim(OBS)
[1]  400 1000
```

400 are the numbers of hours and 1000 the points that I want to compare.
The observation data frame contain also a lot of NA values. So when I try to apply that function on the two data frame:

```
BIAS <- function(x, y) {
    x <- na.omit(x)
    y <- na.omit(y)
    res <- mean(x - y)
}
```

the NA values are removed from the observation data frame, which at the end is empty since there is a least one NA for each line.

How can I reformulate this so that I can perform operation and end up with a new data frame:

```
length(VALUEBIAS)
[1]  1000
```

that contains the bias for all the points?
One solution could be to rotate through the columns, merge them together, remove the NA value and perform the statistics, but I guess that there should be a more elegant way changing the function.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want the `mean` for the whole data or for every `hour`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible example , I can just suggest you try set `na.rm` parameter :

Try this for example:

```
 BIAS <- function(x, y) { mean(x-y,na.rm=TRUE)}
```

But with further information we can maybe vectorize your operation.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I was trying this but I forget to remove the first to line of the function and I was still getting problems. I guess I can apply this also for the rmse like   RMSE <- function(x, y) {
    res <- sqrt(mean(x - y,na.rm=TRUE) ^ 2)  
}

Comment: Actually the first column represent the date. It would be nice to exclude this from the calculation. Otherwise the function report a zero in that position.